# MG2639 & Arduino Uno not GPS-ing?

Tags: gps

is there any way I can run an MG2639 GPS Cellular Shield (the one SparkFun makes) on an Arduino Uno for GPS tracking purposes? It seems whether I use New or AltSoftSerial, the unit just can’t read what’s streaming in through from the GPS on the 115200 baud rate, which the shield is hard-wired to.

Comment: Have you tried sending the baud rate command yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a command that sets the GPS baud rate to something a little lower:

```
altss.write( F("$PMTK251,38400*27\r\n") );
altss.end();
altss.begin( 38400 ); // change to match above command
```

Are you sure you're having trouble *reading*, because there are many other things you may be doing in your sketch that cause input buffer *overflow*.  Please post your code and some sample output for us to examine.  It may be failing for a different reason.

For example, you may just be losing data because you're trying to do too many things in `loop()`.  Please take a look [here](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/doc/Troubleshooting.md#trying-to-do-too-many-things).

To solve this kind of problem, I have posted a modified version of `AltSoftSerial` on github, [here](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoICSerial), that let you process GPS data in the background (i.e., during interrupts).  When coupled with [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS), it can save you quite a bit of program space, RAM and execution time.  There is an interrupt-driven example [here](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/examples/NMEA_isr/NMEA_isr.ino).  Just change which include is uncommented on lines 30-31:

```
#else  
  // Only one serial port is available, uncomment one of the following:
  #include <NeoICSerial.h>
  //#include <NeoSWSerial.h>
#endif
#include "GPSport.h"
```

...and the baud rate below, on line 140:

```
  // Start the UART for the GPS device
  gps_port.attachInterrupt( GPSisr );
  gps_port.begin( 115200 );
}
```